# ScrollView containing ImageView with a lot of buttons

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a ScrollView and inside it I have a map that you can scroll.

On that map I want to place custom buttons, and I need 29 buttons on the map not to move after I place them on the ImageView.

I have placed 13 buttons already but only 8 of them respond to touch, the other ones just don't respond.

Strangely, one of the 8 you have to touch the very top of the button image for it to respond.

Is this because I need to place the map ImageView and buttons in a ContainerView that I would then place in the ScrollView?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.positionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    CGRect node1 = CGRectMake(290, 90, 30, 30);
    [self.positionArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:node1]];

    CGRect node2 = CGRectMake(238, 159, 30, 30);
    [self.positionArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:node2]];

    CGRect node3 = CGRectMake(290, 136, 30, 30);
    [self.positionArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:node3]];

    GRect node4 = CGRectMake(341, 159, 30, 30);
    [self.positionArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:node4]];

    ...

    CGRect node11 = CGRectMake(166, 318, 30, 30);
    [self.positionArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:node11]];

    CGRect node12 = CGRectMake(290, 264, 30, 30);
    [self.positionArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:node12]];

    CGRect node13 = CGRectMake(413, 318, 30, 30);
    [self.positionArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:node13]];

    //self.positionArray = nil;

    self.nodeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i = 0; i < [positionArray count]; i++)
    {
        //Create the button
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:[[self.positionArray objectAtIndex:i] CGRectValue]];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenNode.gif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bigger.gif"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [button setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self.nodeArray addObject:button];
    }

    for(UIButton *button in self.nodeArray)
    {
        //add the button to the view
        [self.mapView addSubview:button];

        //add the action
        //[button addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create the image view?

Comment: I used the storyboard to create the ScrollView and ImageView inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the buttons frames are inside the imageview's frame and the scrollview frame. If an UIView is outside it's parent's frame it does not respond to touch events

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

int x=0;

// DataArray is your image array   
for(int i=0;i<[dataArray count];i++)
{       
    if (i==0) {

       // ImageView used for Display button image in ImageView(When button clicked on image)

        ImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[dataArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    UIButton *btnMap =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnMap.frame=CGRectMake(x, 0, 65, 65 );

    [btnMap setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[dataArray objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    btnMap.tag=i;

    [btnMap addTarget:self action:@selector(btnImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [scrollview addSubview:btnMap];

    x=x+65;

    NSLog(@"print x is..%d",x);

    scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(([dataArray count]*70), 50);
}

//When Button click on Image That time it Display in UiImageview

-(IBAction)btnImage:(id)sender
{

UIButton *btn =(UIButton *)sender;
NSLog(@"button id..%d",btn.tag);
//   return ;

if([dataArray count]>0)
{

    NSLog(@"button name is..%@",[dataArray objectAtIndex:btn.tag]);
   ImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[dataArray objectAtIndex:btn.tag]];

}
}
```